# Changing color of spheres within for loop (python/rhino)

Tags: python, rhino

beginner here with a really simple question--I want to create 6 spheres within spheres, with the one in the middle red, the one on the outside black, and the rest somewhere in between. I'm having trouble with the color--I'm getting the error "iteration over non-sequence of type." Here's my code so far:

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import random

maxNum=6

a=(1/maxNum)

pt0 = [50,50,50]

pts = []
pts.append(pt0)

for i in range (0,6):

    sphere0= rs.AddSphere(pt0, 30*i)

    rs.ObjectColor (sphere0, [(i+1)*2.55,0,0])
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the error message.  Please tells us EXACTLY how it reads and in what line it occurs.  Even better is to give a full traceback.

Comment: OK, here's the full traceback:

Message: iteration over non-sequence of type NoneType

Traceback:
  line 423, in ObjectColor, "/Users/students/Library/Application Support/McNeel/Rhinoceros/MacPlugIns/ironpython/settings/lib/rhinoscript/object.py"
  line 18, in <module>, "/Users/students/Desktop/imagination.py"

Comment: Sorry I did not see your reply earlier.  The traceback is telling you that in line 423 of ObjectColor, an attempt is made to iterate over an object that is None.  That's what "of type NoneType" means.  This function was called from line 18 of your script.  The last line of your script does have a call to ObjectColor, so that makes sense.  You're passing two arguments to this function; the second one is a list so it can't possibly be None.  So the other one is the problem,  What is sphere0 - the return value from AddSphere?  Why don't you print it out and see what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The first sphere you add has radius = 0 so the AddSphere call fails and the GUID returned is none. That's why you can't set the colour.